# Подлинные выражения

Tags: цитаты

> Если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в
> качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания
> ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: *Сказав Гричмару фразу «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).*

---

Вопрос такой: что значит "по условиям авторского предложения"?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что, например, такую фразу можно написать и так:

> *Сказав Гричмару фразу:
> «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на
> себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).*